# How to change the background color of the line numbers mode in emacs?

Tags: emacs, background-color, line-numbers

I have seen some solutions to this using linum and nlinum but is there a way to change the background color of the global line numbers mode?
[I want to make the line number background the same as my normal background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8ZN5.png)

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: ah sorry my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make the line number background the same as my normal background

By default it is, so you must have previously customized it to be that way (or be using a theme which made that change).

Just <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `display-line-numbers` <kbd>RET</kbd> and edit the faces.

Answer (score 3):

For `linum` package, the decoration is defined by the `linum` face, so you can customize it with `M-x customize-face RET linum`.

for `nlinum` the face name is slightly different: `nlinum-current-line`, and you can customize it with `M-x customize-face` as well.

Usually you can call `M-x customize-face` and type the name of the package or something like, and press `TAB` - if face is defined it will be shown.  Other way to discover faces is to call `M-x customize-group` and enter the name of the package - it should include faces as well.  And the last resort is really to look into the source code for strings like `defface` - to open source code, enter `M-x find-library` and give the package name as argument.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are referring to the new built-in line number display, you should customise the line-number face (`M-x customize-face RET line-number RET`) and untick the background option so that it defaults to the default face value.